# Delayed queue / message processing in Storm

Tags: java, clojure, apache-storm

In my [Storm](http://storm-project.net/) topology, while processing a stream, I want to delay the processing of some messages until some future points in time. What are some reasonable options for doing this?

So far, I have thought about the following:

- Using Java's `Thread.sleep`. (However, based on some discussions, this is not a recommended way to efficiently utilize Storm's resources.)
- Use a delayed queue...

  - In particular, try [java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue](http://doc.java.sun.com/DocWeb/api/all/java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue).
  - Are there other implementations worth trying?
- Does Storm have some API for delaying a message that I have overlooked?
- Does ZeroMQ provide a delayed messaging API that Storm (if modified) could take advantage of?

Comment: can you give some idea of why you want to do this? if you're not ready to process this stuff, why are you passing it to your storm topology to begin with?

Comment: My first response: Why ask why? Is it important to understand or answer the question? There are lots of reasons why delaying (or rescheduling) a tuple is useful. My tuple processing is not all about purely functional transformations of data. In my case, processing a tuple involves capturing the state of something outside the system and integrating with other streams. Since it changes over time, I want to capture that state at controlled intervals. One such requirement is not to consume an external resource too often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an external message queue to implement a time-delay queue.

Since Storm is fault-tolerant and horizontally distributed, it would make sense to pick a message queue that fits that style, such as:

- Kafka
- Amazon SQS
- RabbitMQ

Answer (score 5):

We are using topology tick tuples to process pending tuples in bulk. It basically just stores them in memory on every normal tuple and when it receives a tick tuple it processes them into storage/indexing using bulk/pipelined processing.

We also use redis in cases where we have enormous spikes in volume, if a volume spike detected all tuples redirect to local redis storage on each of the hosts and then get pushed back into topology processing after volume dies down. Our situation might not be applicable to yours, just my 2c.